Resolution stuck at 800x600 after installing Nvidia Drivers
Wanted to install Nvidia Drivers on Fedora 40 so I could write CUDA code. I'm actually going to reference this question because it's very similar; only it was asked 7 years ago but received no answers. Matter of fact, I've seen many people with this exact same question, but no answers that have been able to fix the problem. Most solutions centered around installing the drivers through the RPMFusion repository rather than through other means (i.e. through the Nvidia website). I installed from RPMFusion from off the bat so that isn't an issue for me.
I have installed the kmod-nvidia (and akmod-nvidia as well, after kmod didn't work out) package for Fedora 40. After doing this and rebooting, my resolution was stuck at 800x600. The monitor I'm on is 1680x1050. I cannot change the resolution now no matter what I do, and my monitor shows up as "None."
Drivers are 550.76 according to nvidia-smi command.
lspci -d ::03xx -nnv output:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate] [10de:2504] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:881d]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 172
        Memory at a0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at 4010000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidia_drm, nvidia

cat /proc/fb throws "No such directory"
xrandr --listproviders output:
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x41 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting

I'm on a desktop computer with an x86-64 Intel core and an RTX 3060 GPU.
/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch doesn't exist even after mounting debugfs.
I have tried:

Clean install of Fedora 40
Clean install of Fedora 39
Both KDE and Gnome; both X11 and Wayland
Different methods of installing the drivers
Using xrandr to set the resolution through terminal (threw "Size 1680x1050 not found in available modes")


What's the output of lspci -d ::03xx -nnv? What's the output of cat /proc/fb? Is your system a desktop or a laptop? With X11, what is the output of xrandr --listproviders? If you mount debugfs to /sys/kernel/debug (if not already mounted), does /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch exist? If it does, what text does it contain?

Response was too long for one comment so I've edited the question with the relevant information

Just received a system update shortly after updating my original post. It must be brand new because my clean install was late last night and I made sure everything was up-to-date. The issue seems to have been patched in this new update

OK, so it's a desktop and you don't also have an iGPU that might cause its own complications. The kernel-side looks OK: the nvidia module is loaded, and there does not seem to be conflicting nouveau modules active.
But the xrandr --listproviders output indicates the only provider is the generic modesetting instead of something like NVIDIA-0: this indicates the X11 server is not using the correct X11 driver module to go with the NVIDIA kernel module.
That suggests you would have needed a xorg.conf snippet that would contain a Device section that explicitly specifies the nvidia X11 driver module for the GPU. It could be something like this in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/nvidia.conf:
Section "Module"
    Disable        "dri"  # just to silence a warning about obsolete DRI 1.0
EndSection
 
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"   # Selects this module...
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "1:0:0"    # ... for this GPU.
EndSection

I guess the latest system update automatically provided something similar, or otherwise caused the nvidia X11 driver be prioritized higher than the generic modesetting driver.
